# How to change output directory of moduleSet/sources with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to change the output directory of a [`moduleSet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_moduleSet) with [`maven-assemble-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). I tried `moduleSet/sources/outputDirectory`, but I get a strange zip file.

My descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:test-distribution</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <sources>
                <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>sources</outputDirectory>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
            </sources>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

My zip file has following structure:

```
- test-distribution.zip
    - sources
        - src
             - main
             - test
        - target
        - pom.xml  (of first module)
    - src
        - main
        - test
```

Under `/sources` is the hole project instead of only the `src` folder and under `/src`is the source folder.

What I want is:

```
- test-distribution.zip
    - sources
         - main
         - test
```

How can I change the name of the directory of `moduleSet/sources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`fileSet/outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) and [`fileSet/directory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) it is possible to change the name of the source directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:test-distribution</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <sources>
                <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>sources</outputDirectory>
                        <directory>src</directory>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
            </sources>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

But I can't say, what [`sources/outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_sources) should do. This option is very strange.